# How to display node title using computed field?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a computed field (text) where I would like to display the node title.

I tried the following thing but nothing worked.

```
$value = $entity->title;
$entity->title;
```

I referred

1.
https://blogs.sulross.edu/lwetterauer/computed-fields/

2.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087479/how-do-you-access-the-title-node-module-element-field-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value:

```
$value = $entity->title->value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your entity is a "content entity type" such as node

try:

```
$entity->getTitle();
or for term $entity->getName();
```

see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AgetTitle/8.6.x

or 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AgetName/8.6.x

Answer (score 1):

Two lines should do it (set $id to the node you're interested in)

```
$nodeload = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($id);
$title = $nodeload->getTitle();
```